# Django Form Decimal field initial data with 2 decimal places

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a form with a `DecimalField` and I am getting the data from API which I pass as initial input to the form. The `DecimalField` is defined as below:

```
school_fee = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,initial=5.00,required=True")
```

So, I am getting the data as `{'school_fee':u'1234.89373636363'}` and while the input field is rendered in template, it displays the same value as coming from the API and not with 2 decimal places as I defined.

I am thinking of stripping the decimal places in the string I get from the API before passing it to form initial. But I think there could be a better solution.

Comment: Strip the extra digits before passing the form to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

instead of initial write

```
default=Decimal('5.00')
```

may be solved your problem